Added angled corners, but box-shadow overflows into the corners
I am trying to add clipped corners to the main element of my CSS, and I got them working. However, I use box-shadow for elements inside the main element, and large enough shadows near the corners clip outside the main element, only in the corners. This is an example of what I mean:

Example:


* {
  --dark-primary: #8bd5b5;
  --dark-tertiary: #a6cce0;
  --dark-on-tertiary: #093544;
  --border: #68dbaf;
  --light-on-primary-container: #00211699;
  --dark-on-primary-container: #86f8ca;
  --bg-1: #68dbaf;
  --bg-2: #a6cce0;
}

main {
  max-width: 610px;
  margin: auto;
  padding: 10px;
  /* border-top: 1px solid var(--bg-1);
    border-left: 1px solid var(--bg-1);
    border-bottom: 1px solid var(--bg-2);
    border-right: 1px solid var(--bg-2); */
  /* border-radius: 20px; */
  overflow: hidden;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  position: relative;
}

main:before {
  --p: 1;
  --pixel: calc(var(--p) * 1px);
  /* don't change this */
  --s: calc(var(--pixel) * 20);
  /* size of the cut. you can change the number on the right of the asterisk for a deeper or shallower cut */
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  inset: 0;
  z-index: -1;
  background: linear-gradient(45deg, var(--bg-1), var(--bg-2));
  --g1: #000 var(--pixel), #0000 0 calc(100% - var(--pixel)), #000 0;
  --g2: #0000 calc(0.707*var(--s)), #000 0 calc(0.707*var(--s) + var(--pixel)), #0000 0 calc(100% - 0.707*var(--s) - var(--pixel)), #000 0 calc(100% - 0.707*var(--s)), #0000 0;
}

main,
main::before {
  -webkit-mask: linear-gradient(45deg, var(--g2)), linear-gradient(-45deg, var(--g2)), linear-gradient(90deg, var(--g1)) 50%/100% calc(100% - 2*var(--s)) no-repeat, linear-gradient(180deg, var(--g1)) 50%/calc(100% - 2*var(--s)) 100% no-repeat;
  mask: linear-gradient(45deg, var(--g2)), linear-gradient(-45deg, var(--g2)), linear-gradient(90deg, var(--g1)) 50%/100% calc(100% - 2*var(--s)) no-repeat, linear-gradient(180deg, var(--g1)) 50%/calc(100% - 2*var(--s)) 100% no-repeat;
}
<main>
  <div class="box" style="box-shadow: 0 0 100px 0 var(--border);">
    <p><a href="about:blank">archive</a> / old websites</p>
  </div>
  <!-- etc... -->
</main>




Can you show your html as well?

@SamSabin Yes, I have added on my HTML as well

You can use a clip-path on main to hide the content outside, updated example:


* {
  --dark-primary: #8bd5b5;
  --dark-tertiary: #a6cce0;
  --dark-on-tertiary: #093544;
  --border: #68dbaf;
  --light-on-primary-container: #00211699;
  --dark-on-primary-container: #86f8ca;
  --bg-1: #68dbaf;
  --bg-2: #a6cce0;
}

main {
  max-width: 610px;
  margin: auto;
  padding: 10px;
  /* border-top: 1px solid var(--bg-1);
    border-left: 1px solid var(--bg-1);
    border-bottom: 1px solid var(--bg-2);
    border-right: 1px solid var(--bg-2); */
  /* border-radius: 20px; */
  overflow: hidden;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  position: relative;
}

main:before {
  --p: 1;
  --pixel: calc(var(--p) * 1px);
  /* don't change this */
  --s: calc(var(--pixel) * 20);
  /* size of the cut. you can change the number on the right of the asterisk for a deeper or shallower cut */
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  inset: 0;
  z-index: -1;
  background: linear-gradient(45deg, var(--bg-1), var(--bg-2));
  --g1: #000 var(--pixel), #0000 0 calc(100% - var(--pixel)), #000 0;
  --g2: #0000 calc(0.707*var(--s)), #000 0 calc(0.707*var(--s) + var(--pixel)), #0000 0 calc(100% - 0.707*var(--s) - var(--pixel)), #000 0 calc(100% - 0.707*var(--s)), #0000 0;
}

main,
main::before {
  -webkit-mask: linear-gradient(45deg, var(--g2)), linear-gradient(-45deg, var(--g2)), linear-gradient(90deg, var(--g1)) 50%/100% calc(100% - 2*var(--s)) no-repeat, linear-gradient(180deg, var(--g1)) 50%/calc(100% - 2*var(--s)) 100% no-repeat;
  mask: linear-gradient(45deg, var(--g2)), linear-gradient(-45deg, var(--g2)), linear-gradient(90deg, var(--g1)) 50%/100% calc(100% - 2*var(--s)) no-repeat, linear-gradient(180deg, var(--g1)) 50%/calc(100% - 2*var(--s)) 100% no-repeat;
}

/* Clip path to hide outside content */
main {
    --s: 20px;
    clip-path: polygon(var(--s) 0, calc(100% - var(--s)) 0, 100% var(--s), 100% calc(100% - var(--s)), calc(100% - var(--s)) 100%, var(--s) 100%, 0 calc(100% - var(--s)), 0 var(--s));
}
<main>
  <div class="box" style="box-shadow: 0 0 100px 0 var(--border);">
    <p><a href="about:blank">archive</a> / old websites</p>
  </div>
  <!-- etc... -->
</main>



